# Cuda-memcheck and JOCL, can a java executable make use of it? (OpenCL)

Tags: java, c++, exe, opencl, memcheck

I love JOCL, Java bindings for OpenCL. I would like to run Cuda-memcheck on an executable from Java, but whenever I make Java applications, they are always just JAR files that point to a Main-Class. Is there a way to create a .exe file like C++ does and feed that to Cuda-memcheck?

Answer (score 0):

This link could be useful: http://jsmooth.sourceforge.net/index.php

You could probably also the jvm executable directly and provide all the arguments necessary to run your java application. If you normally run your java applications through an IDE, check the console output to see what command the IDE uses to launch your app. This command should resemble something like: `<path-to-java-exe> [JVM arguments] main_class [application arguments]`.

Answer (score 0):

You might try looking into one of the Windows ports of the [gcc toolchain](http://gcc.gnu.org).  I know that gcc has the capability to turn java code into compiled binary, which is what Cuda-memcheck is looking for.  If you aren't afraid of a lot of unnecessary output, attaching Cuda-memcheck to the call to the JVM should also work.